# How see remote file list from a heroku server

Tags: heroku

I need to see all files from a heroku server from a directory. Is any anyway run command in server using command line or is there file browser heroku dashboard?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could see the files from command line using the following command

```
heroku run ls private
```

But i could not find any file browser in heroku dashboard. Also we could all linux commands there by using `heroku run`